# Warning message extracting query parameters from an Akka-HTTP route

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm working with Akka-HTTP for the first time and am having some issues constructing a route to handle GET requests with multiple parameters.  Here's a simplified version of my route-- it takes in 2 query parameters and then just wraps them in a case class and returns them in JSON format (using Circe):

```
def echo(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) = Future.successful { Coordinates(latitude, longitude) }

    val route = get {
      pathPrefix("foo") {
        path("echo") {
          parameters('latitude.as[Double], 'longitude.as[Double]) { 
            (latitude, longitude) =>
              complete(echo(latitude, longitude))
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Although this works as expected, I'm getting the following warning during compilation:

> "No automatic adaptation here: use explicit parentheses. [warn]
>   signature: ParameterDirectives.parameters(pdm:
>   akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ParameterDirectives.ParamMagnet):
>   pdm.Out [warn]   given arguments: scala.Symbol("latitude").as[Double],
>   scala.Symbol("longitude").as[Double] [warn]  after adaptation:
>   ParameterDirectives.parameters((scala.Symbol("latitude").as[Double],
>   scala.Symbol("longitude").as[Double]):
>   akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ParameterDirectives.ParamMagnet{type
>   Out = akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive[(Double, Double)]}) [warn]
>   parameters('latitude.as[Double], 'longitude.as[Double]) { (latitude,
>   longitude) =>"

Following a different example, I tried the following route, but although it compiles without any warnings, it always returns a 404:

```
  val route = get {
    pathPrefix("foo") {
      path("echo" / DoubleNumber / DoubleNumber) { 
        (latitude, longitude) =>
          complete(echo(latitude, longitude))
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone knows how I can fix the warning with the first route or get the second route to work, I would really appreciate the help. Also, the real service I'm working on will have 4 GET methods-- different paths and return types, but they will all have the same 4 parameters.  Is there a way to structure this to minimize boilerplate when writing the routes?  Again, I'm very new to Akka-HTTP, so any suggestions or advice would be very much appreciated!

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) the compiler is wrapping your parameters together with auto-tupling, and you're likely to have a compiler flag that throws warnings in this case (`scala -Ywarn-adapted-args` ?). The fix would be to make the tupling explicit, e.g.

```
parameters(('latitude.as[Double], 'longitude.as[Double])) {...}
```

2) This one looks just fine. The sample main below

```
object Main extends App {
  val route = get {
    pathPrefix("foo") {
      path("echo" / DoubleNumber / DoubleNumber) {
        (latitude, longitude) =>
          complete(latitude + ":" + longitude)
      }
    }
  }

  implicit val sys = ActorSystem()
  implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

  Http().bindAndHandle(route, "0.0.0.0", 9080)
}
```

works fine with the following request

> http://localhost:9080/foo/echo/2.356/25.6346

3) For what concerns extracting bits of logic to reusable functions, that's what **Directives** are for. Say you want to extract the bit that matches lat and lng params, you could do something like:

```
  def extractLatLng(prefix: String): Directive[(Double, Double)] = path(prefix / DoubleNumber / DoubleNumber)

  val route = get {
    pathPrefix("foo") {
      extractLatLng("echo") { (lat, lng) ⇒
        complete(lat + ":" + lng)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: That route works, but it's a different URL than what's produced by the first route-- the first route includes the parameter names and separates them using ampersands, while the second does not have the parameter names and they are separated by slashes.  So when I test the first route using httpie or Postman  (with httpie:  "http GET :8080/foo/echo latitude==47.5 longitude==-91.1", with Postman (or just the browser): "localhost:8080/foo/echo?latitude=47.5&longitude=-91.1").  I've only seen query parameters in the latter format...Are they both considered valid?  Is one to be preferred?

Comment: to choose between query parameters and path parameters is a different issue, and not an akka-http specific one. I suggest you look around for guidelines on that.

Comment: I appreciate the help...Thanks!